# synchronous http.get angular 2, ionic 2

Tags: angular, ionic2

I have a problem with asynchronous http.get. In loop I have http.get and I think - in this case - better will be synchronous method. What do you think? How can I solve this problem?

I use Ionic 2.

Below is my code:

```
for (var key in this.beacons) {
    alert('beacon id: ' + this.beacons[key]['url']);
    this.http.get('http://website.com/app.php?id=' + this.beacons[key]['url']).map(res => res.json()).subscribe(
              data => {
                  this.json = data.config;
                  alert('alert json, id: ' + this.beacons[key]['url']);
              }, error => {
                  this.jsonError = true;
              });

    if (this.json['id']) {
        alert('alert end, id: ' + this.beacons[key]['url']);
        break;
    }
}
```

At the beginning I get about 10 alerts "beacon id", and in the end I get "alert json".

What I want to achieve:

1. In array I have about 10 items
2. Every loop do request to my server with beacon's url
3. Only few beacons gets array in response
4. When I get first JSON response with config array, I want to break the loop

The problem is that the answer comes late and I cannot keep the interrupt loop etc.

Answer (score 0):

If you want your ajax call to be synced, I think you can implement a recursive method. So, after the first ajax calls, if you don't get your desired response, you can call the method again with different url

example:

```
let arr = [];
for(var key in this.beacons){
  arr.push(key);
}
function callAjax(index){
  if(index >= arr.length){
    return;
  }else{
    //YOUR AJAX CALL...
    data => {
      this.json = data.config;
    }, error => {callAjax(index + 1)}
  }
}
```

for the first call

```
callAjax(0);
```